# How to pass props of a nested object to a component?

Tags: reactjs

I am having a little hard time figuring out this issue and would appreciate if someone clear this concept to me. With the following code, I can parse props to another component i.e. UserItem and it displays the username and email. I also want to display "firstname" along with other details. I can easily destructure others like: `const {username, email} = this.state.user` but when I add const {name: fisrtname, username, email}, then it doesn't work. But if I put `this.state.user.name.firstname` in the UserItem component, then I can see the firstname in the browser. So how I will destructure the nested object and/or parse the props of nested object to other component? Thanks in advance.

```
    users: [
      {
        username: "johndoe",
        email: "jdoe@gmail.com",
        name: {
          firstname: "John",
          id: "2",
        },
        id: "1",
      },
    ],
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.users.map((user) => (
          <UserItem key={user.id} user={user} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

**This is UserItem component**

class UserItem extends Component {
  render() {
    const { name: firstname, email, username, phone } = this.props.user;
    // console.log(this.props.user);

    return (
      <div>
        <h3>{this.props.user.name.firstname}</h3>
        <h3>{email}</h3>
        <h3>{username}</h3>
        <h3>{phone}</h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just extending and describing the @Alex Yepes's Answer.
Look at your code

```
{
    username: "johndoe",
    email: "jdoe@gmail.com",
    name: {                   // here the name is also an object.
      firstname: "John",
      id: "2",
    },
    id: "1",
  },
```

Since 'name' is also an object you need to destructure that one too.
For example:
On your first destructure, you can only access directly the property of that object

```
const {username, email, name, id} = user;
console.log(username); //result: 'johndoe'
console.log(name); //result: {firstname: 'John', id: 2}
```

Here you can see that username's value is a string but the value of 'name' is an object that's why you need to destructure this one too. Other wise you have to use object or bracket notation like:

```
console.log(name.firstname); // result: 'John' 
//or 
console.log(name[firstname]) // result: 'John'
```

But if you destructure like this one:

```
const { name: {firstname}, email, username, phone } = this.props.user;
```

you can access 'name' directly because the 'name' object is not an object anymore.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I would like to ask here that for instance I have multiple entries in the name object too e.g. firstname, lastname, age etc. So have I to use another map function to render the props of name object? or simply destructuring the same way as I did with only one entry?

Comment: @xiang yeah, you should simply destructuring because map doesn't work with object. map only work with Array.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
const { name: firstname, email, username, phone } = this.props.user;
```

needs to be changed to this:

```
const { name: {firstname}, email, username, phone } = this.props.user;
```

That way you can access the nested property.

Comment: No problem, please choose it as the answer if it helped you, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you need the constructor in the object above the render.

```
class UserItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  render() {
```